# Postgres dynamic evaluation

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, evaluation

I would like to record dynamic rules in a postgres table.

**For example:**

- I have a table: `Tstudents`, with the following columns: `Cid:serial Cname:varchar, Cmajor:varchar, CGPAGrades:float, Ccreditscompleted:integer, CthesisScore`.
- I also have a table for `Trules`, with the following columns: `Cmajor:Varchar, CSomeRules:Varchar.`

If a student is a major in **engineering** I would the following rules would be evaluated CSomeRules which probably will say: `creditcompleted>40, CGPAGrades>3.5, thesisScore>8`

1. We record the rules in a table `Trules`
2. the rules is dynamic in the sense that `creditcompleted>40, CGPAGrades>3.5, thesisScore>8` can become the following on the next semester: `creditcompleted>40, CGPAGrades>3.5` we dropped one of the requirement. Or `creditcompleted * CGPAGrades > somevalue`
3. The rules might change often, that's why if possible to record the rules on a table, nothing should be hard-coded. Maybe what I need is something similar to javascript `eval` concept.

How do I do that in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You compose an SQL statement using your rules and run it against the database.

You can either do that in client code or in a PL/pgSQL function using [`EXECUTE 'command string'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Make sure you can trust the source where the rules come from, since you are at the risk of SQL injection attacks if you dynamically construct SQL statements from user input.